# Git rebase: How are manually merged files handled?

Tags: git

During a rebase, I encountered merge conflicts that I manually edited and added. It seems to me that since this manual process might be done incorrectly, such files should be distinguished in some way. The specific situation I am dealing with is this: I have modified some files which are part of a commit which I am submitting for review using Code Collaborator -- I specify this commit and those files can be seen by the reviewer. Would the manually merged files not also be added to this same commit or are they added to a different commit or what?

Answer (score 0):

That's a limitation of using rebase versus merge. If you want the tracking, use 'git merge'. (This coming from an advocate of 'git rebase'.)

Comment: okay, given that I have done rebase already, what should I do?